# css scale works strangely on this div

Tags: css, scale

I have jquery adding a class to scale a div in certain circumstances:

```
$("#wrapper").addClass("doubleDiv");
```

The css:

```
.doubleDiv{ transform: scale(2); }

#wrapper { height:100%; position:relative; z-index:2; background-color:#111;  max-width:320px; min-height:480px; margin:0px auto; }
```

It doubles the size fine, but the div's content gets shifted up past the top of the browser, so that roughly the top third is hidden, and you cannot scroll further up.

I removed each of the styles in #wrapper one by one, until none were left. Apart from screwing up the layout, the same thing happens when the scale is carried out.

To eliminate the chance of any of my jquery causing it, I coded

```
    alert('stop1');
    $("#wrapper").addClass("doubleDiv");
    alert('stop2');
```

The display problem occurs before 'stop2' is displayed.

What else could cause this?

Cheers

Comment: A simple JSFiddle would be nice.

Comment: maybe because you have a height:100% set it is scaling the height to 200% as well as scaling the width to 640px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/72mhqonp/1/)**

you need to add `transform-origin`

css

```
.doubleDiv {
    transform: scale(2);
    transform-origin:50% 0%;
    -ms-transform-origin:50% 0%;/* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform-origin:50% 0%; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Transform scale scales the object in place. Use transform-origin to define from where you want to scale. Because scaling does not affect positioning at all and the default scaling point is `center centre`, it moves off screen. Check the follow code to see how it solves this problem:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    #div {
        -webkit-transform: scale(2,2); 
        -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
        background: red; 
        width: 100px; 
        height: 100px; 
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```